# SearchBar with TabLayout and Viewpager. SearchBar (EditText) doesn't filter through users, nor events

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

My `SearchFragment` is the host Fragment for two other Fragments: `SearchUsersFragment` and `SearchEventsFragment`. The way I have it organized is the `TabLayout` and `Viewpager` are in the `SearchFragment`, and the `RecyclerView`, `Adapters`, and `ArrayList` are in the two child Fragments.

What I would like to do is implement a **SearchBar** (`EditText`), which I have already done in the `SearchFragment` and use that `SearchBar` to filter through the users (in `SearchUsersFragment`) and events (in `SearchEventsFragment`).

**The problem:** is I have written two methods in each child Fragment `searchusers();` and `readUsers();`. The method `searchUsers();` I made public so that I can add it to the SearchFragment in `onTextChangedListener`, but still the users whose names begin with the letters that I type into the SearchBar aren't coming up.

Can someone **please** tell me how to fix this? I have been working on this for 3 days and can't get the users or events to come up that start with the letters someone types in the SearchBar.

**SearchFragment**

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        final TabLayout tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        final ViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_people_black));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_event_available_black));

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new SearchUsersFragment(), "");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new SearchEventsFragment(), "");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));

        EditText searchBar = v.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
                SearchUsersFragment searchUsersFragment = (SearchUsersFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_search_users);
                if (searchUsersFragment != null) {
                    searchUsersFragment.searchUsers(s.toString().toLowerCase());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments;
        private ArrayList<String> mTitles;

        ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            this.mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
            this.mTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchUsersFragment**

```
public class SearchUsersFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    List<User> mUserList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_users, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUserList, true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);

        readUsers();

        return view;
    }

    public void searchUsers(String s) {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("username").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUserList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (user != null) {
                        mUserList.add(user);
                    }
                }

                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readUsers() {
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUserList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (firebaseUser != null && user != null && !user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        mUserList.add(user);
                    }
                }

                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**SearchEventsFragment**

```
public class SearchEventsFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    SearchEventsAdapter mSearchEventsAdapter;
    List<Post> mPostList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_events, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        mPostList = new ArrayList<>();
        mSearchEventsAdapter = new SearchEventsAdapter(getContext(), mPostList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSearchEventsAdapter);

        readEvents();

        return view;
    }

    private void readEvents() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mPostList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    if (post != null) {
                        mPostList.add(post);
                    }
                }

                mSearchEventsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a searchView here for filtering 3 fragments together

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            fAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            rAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And then in my adapters I have done **implements Filterable** and

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return myFilter;
}

private Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        ArrayList<String> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filterList.addAll(MainActivity.Db.getWholeData());
        } else {
            String toFilter = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (String item : MainActivity.Db.getWholeData()) {
                if (item.toLowerCase().contains(toFilter)) {
                    filterList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        clickPurposeFav = filterList;
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        filterResults.values = filterList;

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {          

        MainActivity.arrList.clear();
        MainActivity.arrList.addAll((List) results.values);

     }
};
```

Comment: Where do I implement the SearchView? In which Fragment should I have it in the SearchFragment or in the other two Fragments SearchUserFragment and SearchEventFragment?

Comment: you can implement the search view in the parent activity

Comment: I have been trying to do that, but I haven't been able to because the Adapters are in the other classes. I just updated my code to how I have it now, but really not sure how to take care of the Adapter situation

Comment: Just define a public function like refreshEvents()  and refreshUsers() in your SearchEventsFragment and SearchUsersFragment. In your SearchFragment declare your both child as members. Now every time you want to refresh your child fragments call mSearchEventsfragment.refreshEvents(list) or mSearchUsersFragment.refreshUsers(list)

Comment: @M_droid I'm not exactly sure how to do what you are telling me. So in my Child Fragments I have to create a method called refreshUsers(); and refreshEvents(); and then the rest of the code write it in the SearchFragment which is the Parent Fragment?

Comment: @M_droid I just updated my code. Could you tell me if that's what you meant? I wrote a method in ```SearchUsersFragment``` called ```SearchUsers();```, and then I initialized it in ```SearchFragment```. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @JMB in your OnTextChanged just do the adapter.getFIlter.filter(s) for each adapter, and just implement Filterable and the filtering code that I have given, in the adapter classes. I think that should work

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly should I remove the method I have there now or leave it?

Comment: @JMB yes that's right. Actually fragmentManager.findview... should return the right instance but I would define the child fragment globally in SearchFragment and init them once and call em in onTextChanged like mSearchUsersFragment.searchUsers(s.toString().toLowerCase());

Comment: @M_droid okay man, so I changed what you said, but I got a null pointer for some reason... Could it be because of ```mSearchUsersFragment.searchUsers(s.toString().toLowerCase());```? Not sure why I am getting the null pointer...

Comment: @M_droid I took care of the null pointer, but when I type in the search box still no names starting with those letters come up... Any idea as to why that might be? And just saw that you added something to your last answer, and I did just that... but I am still typing and no users are coming up that begin with those letters . Just updated the code to show you what it is like now.

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly hey buddy, I still can't get this SearchView to work and it actually crashes now. Do you mind if we chat? Maybe you can explain what I am doing wrong...?

Comment: @can you post the crash report and the code that you have written?

Comment: @M_droid hey man, I was wondering if you could tell me what to do. I changed it like you said, made mSearchUsersFragment global and it's still not returning back the users who fit the letters in the Search Box...

Comment: @M_droid I figured it out. Really simple way to do it. Thanks for the help man!

Comment: Never have a static variable to an Activity.